# Статистика регистрации пользователей по timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

Есть таблица с пользователями, дата регистрации в timestamp. Подскажите с запросом, как можно вывести сколько было зарегистрировано по каждому дню, за каждый месяц. К примеру получить массив с 12 месяцами и сколько в каждом из месяцев было зарегистрировано пользователей.

Comment: Сформировать метки времени начального и конечного месяцев, затем вытащить количество записей, которые находятся в промежутке от начального месяца до конечного.

Comment: хорошо если за оддин или два месяца, а если нужно по дням и за год?

Comment: Ну тогда, думаю, можно выбрать все записи и уже разбирать из с помощью PHP.

Comment: @w3lifer да можно было бы, но 10 000 записей это я думаю будет сложно. Говорят можно такие запросы кормить в mysql но я вот не совсем в курсе этих дел :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вывод год, месяц, день и количество

```
SELECT YEAR( FROM_UNIXTIME( user_time ) ) AS yer,
MONTH( FROM_UNIXTIME( user_time ) ) AS 
MONTH , DAY( FROM_UNIXTIME( user_time ) ) AS 
DAY , COUNT( * ) AS cnt
FROM user
GROUP BY 1 , 2, 3
WITH ROLLUP
```

Выведет:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [yer] => 2011
            [month] => 5
            [day] => 10
            [cnt] => 20
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [yer] => 2011
            [month] => 6
            [day] => 14
            [cnt] => 8
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [yer] => 2011
            [month] => 7
            [day] => 8
            [cnt] => 22
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [yer] => 2011
            [month] => 8
            [day] => 17
            [cnt] => 10
        )

/* Вырезано :))) */

    [62] => Array
        (
            [yer] => 2016
            [month] => 2
            [day] => 1
            [cnt] => 59
        )

    [63] => Array
        (
            [yer] => 2016
            [month] => 3
            [day] => 13
            [cnt] => 44
        )

    [64] => Array
        (
            [yer] => 2016
            [month] => 
            [day] => 13
            [cnt] => 147
        )

    [65] => Array
        (
            [yer] => 
            [month] => 
            [day] => 13
            [cnt] => 4184
        )

)
```

P.S. Сам спросил сам ответил, всем спасибо. Можете дальше пинать.

Comment: Если честно то ничего не понятно, что в итоге получилось. А ваши переменные с ума могут свести :); по-моему лучше так `year_from_table_of_registration`, чем `yer`; аналогично `cnt`, лучше уж `count_of_registartions`. Ну так к делу ... Возьмём первую ячейку: `'yer' => 2011, 'month' => 5, 'day' => 10, 'cnt' => 20`. Это я так понимаю 10 Мая 2011 года было 20 регистраций. Тогда почему следующая дата 2011-06-14? Что, в один день в Мае зарегистрировалось 20 человек, а потом месяц никто не регился до 14 числа? Поясните, пожалуйста, или дайте ссылку на источник, самому интересна тема.

Comment: @w3lifer что касается переменных то я думаю что это дело каждого, и я не это решил тут обсудить. По поводу того что не кто не регистрировался, а что такого не бывает?  У вас есть вариант лучше? Напишите его в ответ, возможно это так и я буду вам очень благодарен.